# Cannot download documents in drives other than system drive in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, hard-drive, 22.04, browser

Recently I switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and whenever I try to download files from any browser(chrome,brave,firefox) I cannot download files in any other drivers other than system drive. All my drives are mounted, I can read, write and delete file too but whenever I download and try to save in those drives at that time the files does not save.
Please, tell me what to do?

Comment: Understand the problem: The software mentioned is now installed as a snap therefore confined by default. You can search for each one in Ubuntu Software, click Permissions and enable access to other locations (note: only what's under /media or /mnt can be enabled, not other less common mount points).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Can you please tell me how to enable permission.

Comment: I just did. Please read the above comment again.